# How to get around triangles?

Tags: modeling

Im very new to blender, so this is probably a very simple question, I guess thats why i haven't really found a solution online for it. Ive been working on other 3d softwares that just doesn't handle certain situations the same!

Basically my question is how to skip using triangles when working on a model. for example the screenshot ill be attaching, i have my base of the mesh finished, and then i wanna extrude a part of the mesh which will create triangles or actually in this case even worse, Ngons.

Basically i used the knife tool to cut out the part of the mesh i wanna extrude, i thought about using loopcuts But that would create just so many more faces, faces i don't really need.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I don't trust the knife tool unless it's to do something very specific. It can make lots of irregular faces if used as a freehand tool. I'd rather stick to loopcuts and not worry about the extra faces.

Judging from your second screenshot, seems like you're trying to make some kind of piece/emblem from your current mesh (which is starting to look pretty weird). I'd recommend to make that part as a different object and then join or parent to your first object.

Comment: Well, i agree, its very hard to trust the knife tool, I guess i might use the loop cut instead.One problem though, sometimes on bigger models the loop cut doesn't work as well for me, i guess its because i might not line up all verts like they should, but i might focus on getting my verts to line up better!

Comment: Also, on the second part, i would join it if it could be a different object, but really, what I'm doing right now is a jerry can. If you check out some jerry cans, they really have that emblem as part of the metal/surface, so thats why join wouldn't quite work, unless you talk about some other function, that actually join those two as one!

Comment: I really recommend doing the piece in your second screenshot as a separate object because its shape goes diagonally, so you're either going to have to use triangles, or end up with a deformed mesh. Also, if you work with separate objects, you can do modifications to one piece without affecting the rest of the pieces when doing things like loop cuts.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Looks like the kind of things you can do with textures or bump maps; you could look into that, because modeling that shape is going to be hard.

Comment: Well, I'll try using triangles, cause i really need it to be integrated to the model, and the more i think about it, the more i realize how hard it would be to create without any triangles!

Comment: Just one last thing. Google "jerry can model" or "modeling a jerry can". You can see images of wireframes (they do look complex) and a couple of videos. Hope that helps.